# Images not getting displayed while running app.[shows image on IB]

Tags: ios, xcode, imageview

I am currently using XCode 8.3.3 and when running my application on a physical device or the simulator it is not showing images in image views.

As you can see the images are correctly displayed in the preview.

The hidden property is not selected and the alpha is 1, the content mode is scale to fill.

Not sure what else I can check, I've attached the constraints in case it's that.

[image: Images not showing]

Comment: Do you use Assets catalog?

Comment: add 2x and 3x images properly.

Comment: No I will look at that now

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov That worked, oops. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: You must have not checked the copy items if needed when you imported the image> and for reference. Use assets catalog and you can have retina images